# Chrome unwanted blurry div border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue with Chrome webbrowser render: 
I have two elements side by side, and i have this grey annoy border in the middle:

[image: Chrome][image: Firefox][image: Edge]

this happens in sertains screens resolutions and only in chrome. I already check for outline, border, radius, margins and padding.
I am using Chrome v 75.

Anyone have a solution for this kind of problem?
Both components have this css properties:

```
height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

the main grit hav this properties:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 170px auto;
height: 100%;
```

you can see a simplified mockup [here](https://js-8klwst.stackblitz.io/)
you can see the problem at 1366 X 768 screen size

Comment: this two elements are set as display:inline-block? please post some code without it how can we help you?

Comment: their have display: flex

Comment: set the background to their container

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I can set the background color to hide this, but i hoped there was a better solution

Comment: obviously there is a better solution. But we haven't enough clues to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195280/discussion-between-ernesto-alfonso-and-sfili-81).